# Secret Manager can't invoke specified lambda function. even though lambda invoke policy is configured

Tags: aws-lambda, rotation, aws-secrets-manager

Secret manager rotation throws following error while configuring lambda
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFgbw.png)
I have applied below permission and invokefunction policy
[Lambda policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvZhg.png)
Role permissions for lambda
[Role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWEnT.png)

AWS Secret manager should invoke lambda